# How to Set Image to imageview in recycler view from Firebase using Glide?

Tags: android, firebase, android-context, android-glide

I'm trying to set the image on the Image View as I have done the text using TextView.setText(String);

Now I need to retrieve the image from the firebase and I'm making the list of the users. Now every user have an image as they have a name and email.

I am able to retrieve the name and email. But the problem is that by using Glide library I exactly know how to retrieve the image, As I'm using a NON Activity Class I don't have the context. Also I'm not able to pass it.

[image]

I want to know how can I have the context in that non activity class.

---

This is the class in which I want to get the context to get my work done.

[image: Check This Image]

Comment: post your java class and adapter class here please

Comment: I just need a context? I want to know how can I get that in my adapter class

Answer (score 0):

make adapter constructor and pass context like this ..

```
private Context context;
private List<student> student=new ArrayList();
public RecyclerViewAdaper(Context context,List<Student> studentlist){
context=context;
studnetlist=studentlist;
}
```

this is my adapter ....

```
public class RecyclerViewAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdpater.ItemViewHolder> {
List<String> mStringList = new ArrayList<>();// hear you can pass any pojo class object.
Context mContext;

public RecyclerViewAdpater(List<String> mStringList, Context mContext) {
    this.mStringList = mStringList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    String data=mStringList.get(position);
    holder.textview.setText(data);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mStringList.size();
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeData);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ItemData[] itemsData;
 private Context context;
    public MyAdapter(,Context context,ItemData[] itemsData) {
      this.context= context;
        this.itemsData = itemsData;
    }
}
```

Now Set adapter
if its a fragment use this

```
MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),itemsData);
```

else

```
MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(ActivtyClassName.this,itemsData);
    // set adapter
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks I think I got the answer